# How to fix these from moving

Tags: javascript, html

I recently asked how to use a progress bar, no one answered so I made up a custom progress bar, Its perfect but the [ ] expand out every new increment, is this due to the font width? or is it fixable? I used `&nbsp;` because it would have expanded in the first place.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var imgsb = new Array("[/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[///&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[///////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[///////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[///////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[///////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[////////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//////////////////////&nbsp;]","[///////////////////////]");
altb = new Array();
var currentAdb = 0;
var imgCtb = 25;
function cycleb() {
  if (currentAdb == imgCtb) {
    currentAdb = 0;
  }
document.getElementById('adLinkb').innerHTML = imgsb[currentAdb];
  currentAdb++;
}
  window.setInterval("cycleb()",500);
</script>
<div style="font-size:12px;color:#fff;font-family:monospace;" id="adLinkb">[/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]</div>
```

Comment: It is likely because &nbsp; is not exactly the same width as a slash /

Comment: Ok thankyou, is there any fix? or should I just use a new loaded letter?

Comment: yes, try a fixed-width font like courier. On a side note, there's may be better ways to do this without such arrays and such. I would look at CSS values on 2 divs. `<div style="background-color: #FF0000"><div id="done" style="width:1%; height: 20px; background-color:#00FF00"></div></div>` and then use the JS to change the width.

Comment: Just an advice: never use such syntax: `window.setInterval("cycleb()",1000);`. You can do it without evaling:
`window.setInterval(cycleb, 1000);`

Comment: I fixed it, but how can I make it so it loads on mouse hover event like it'll start loading when you hover over an image, like certain banner ads on forums.. new code is in OP

Comment: Nvm I figured it out

Comment: Not sure why would anyone downvote this... Anyway, why don't you try to make that array programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See how much cleaner this looks:

```js
var currentAdb = 0;
var imgCtb = 25;

function cycleb() {
  var output = '[';
  for (var i = 0; i < imgCtb; i++) {
    output += i > currentAdb ? '&nbsp;' : '/';
  }
  output += ']';
  document.getElementById('adLinkb').innerHTML = output;
  ++currentAdb;
  if(currentAdb == imgCtb) {
    window.clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
}
var myInterval = window.setInterval(cycleb, 500);
```

```css
#adLinkb {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="adLinkb"></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Absolutely. You know how to kill an interval?

Comment: No, tbh thats not my code I got it from htmlbasix.com and just edited it, didn't notice the loop till now. I got some more questions too, you have teamviewer and skype or other means of conversation so we don't keep bumping this? (Idk if they do get bumped but easier to because I have like 5 more questions).

Comment: The key is to assign the setInterval to a variable, and then you can run clearInterval on it, see my update.

Comment: Why don't you post those 5 questions here on Stack Overflow? There are people who can give you much better answers than I can. :)

Comment: Ok, its just I used an outdated source that worked and no one would answer me and flammed me for it, this is the second real answer Ive gotten.

Comment: I just saw your other question. I can understand why you got flamed - it doesn't show any research effort, there's a lot of code (try showing just the relevant pieces), and thus it's not really clear what you're asking. But this one is much better, and I already gave you an upvote. You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And **welcome to SO!**

Comment: I read it, heres the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287901/javascript-loading-bar

Answer (score 0):

@Dave Goten answered this
Thank you all for helping me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgsb = new Array("[/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[///&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[///////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[///////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[///////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[///////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[////////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[/////////////////////&nbsp;&nbsp;]","[//////////////////////&nbsp;]","[///////////////////////]");
altb = new Array();
var currentAdb = 0;
var imgCtb = 25;
function cycleb() {
  if (currentAdb == imgCtb) {
    currentAdb = 0;
  }
document.getElementById('adLinkb').innerHTML = imgsb[currentAdb];
  currentAdb++;
}
  window.setInterval("cycleb()",500);
</script>
<div style="font-size:12px;color:#fff;font-family:monospace;" id="adLinkb">[/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]</div>
```