# Javascript loading bar

Tags: javascript, html

how would I make a loading bar, I would also like it to be "stackable" like have 2 on the same page and have the first one trigger the second one when its complete then the second one redirects to a URL at 100%, this may or may not be basic to you guys but its really hard for me. I have an outdated JavaScript one already but it disappears when I add the second one and don't know how to make it trigger the second one. if you want to try and edit the one I have so It triggers the second one and is stackable then just say so, but note its outdated, I know that, I am using it because it is really simple to configure and setup.

This is the relevant code so far:

```js
var currentAdb = 0;
var imgCtb = 25;

function cycleb() {
  var output = '[';
  for (var i = 0; i < imgCtb; i++) {
    output += i > currentAdb ? '&nbsp;' : '/';
  }
  output += ']';
  document.getElementById('adLinkb').innerHTML = output;
  ++currentAdb;
  if(currentAdb == imgCtb) {
    window.clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
}
var myInterval = window.setInterval(cycleb, 500);
```

```css
#adLinkb {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="adLinkb"></div>
```

Comment: If someone asked you this question, would you be able to answer it without knowing the insider information of your situation?

Comment: Well the tags say javascript and HTML, all I need is some snippets, I tried most of the tutorials and generators, they don't stack or don't trigger the required urls

Comment: I told you you need to provide a better context in the question, @TravisJ is right. I've added the code I wrote for you in the last question.

Comment: Ohhh, Ok this will do, I didn't understand what he was getting at, I was trying for the question the got flammed type of loading bar but this will be even better if this is possible

Comment: No worries, you'll get used to how thing work here. But try to keep each question isolated. Imagine if you had to go through all the questions of a user who has hundreds of them, just to be able to find the context of what's going on. Try to be as concise and specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's expand the code I gave you in the last question by grouping it into functions and introducing callbacks:

```js
function buildBar(id, callback) {
  var currentAdb = 0;
  var imgCtb = 25;

  function cycleb() {
    var output = '[';
    for (var i = 0; i < imgCtb; i++) {
      output += i > currentAdb ? '&nbsp;' : '/';
    }
    output += ']';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = output;
    ++currentAdb;
    if (currentAdb == imgCtb) {
      window.clearInterval(myInterval);
      if (typeof callback == 'function') {
        callback();
      }
    }
  }
  var myInterval = window.setInterval(cycleb, 500);
}

function callback1() {
  buildBar('adLinkb2', callback2);
}

function callback2() {
  //window.location... stuff here
  alert('redirect should go here');
}

buildBar('adLinkb', callback1);
```

```css
#adLinkb,
#adLinkb2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="adLinkb"></div>
<div id="adLinkb2"></div>
```

Comment: Ok this is perfect, 1 thing, would I edit the div to make it have them look like a border like so I keep them like [                          ] or something else ill have to edit, and shomz thank you so much for all of your kind help and suggestions

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can also add them to a container div, and give border to that one... Infinite possibilities. :) You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Ok so I tried doing the border thing but it doesn't show `<div  id="adLinkb" style="border:thin;border-color:black;"></div>`

Comment: You also need to specify type. Remember this setup for borders: `border: 1px solid black;`

Comment: Im sorry Im an idiot, what function do I call? or is this .js? because I tryed all and just now saved it as js and it didn't work. sorry for my stupidity

Comment: That is CSS, the same thing you wrote just above it. :)

Comment: Shomz, Is it possible to make it have random delay's like actual loading? Like not harsh but like every random tick it'll change to 500 milliseconds then a second later it'll be normal again?

Comment: Yes, you can use setTimeout in every cycle call with a random delay instead of one setInterval.